# save the state for table items

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have one requirement that I need to mark  the table item when the user has already viewed that item in the table.
It is exactly like emails in the inbox. when the user reads the mail, the font will be changed to normal. The same way I need to implement. For that I used Font for the table. Now i need to save the state for the table item. When the application restarts, the table item which the user has already viewed should be seen as viewed item. I mean normal font. Is ther any way to save the state for the table item?

Thanks
Bhanu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative - if we are only talking very little data, e.g. a pointer to the last read item - you can use the view state. See `IViewPart.init(IViewSite site, IMemento memento)` and `IViewPart.saveState(IMemento memento)`. This method is not very useful if you have lots of data as the storage is rather ineffective.

Answer (score 0):

If your bundle activator subclasses `org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin` or `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin` you can use `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin.getStateLocation()` to get your plugin state location.  You can use `java.io.File` and FileReader/FileWriter to store information there across sessions.  See `org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin.saveDialogSettings()` for an example of how a this plugin stores dialog settings there.